# How can I make example.com and www go to http://www.example.com/wiki/projects?

Tags: macos, server.app

With OS X Server Websites, how can I make example.com and www.example.com to go directly to http://​www.example.com/wiki/projects

I have wikis setup correctly. I want visitors that come to example.com and www.example.com to see http://​www.example.com/wiki/projects directly.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the server app. Go to the websites menu and under the "Server Website" click the pen icon to edit. The add a redirect of "http://​www.example.com" and/or "http://​example.com" to "http://​example.com/wiki/projects"

Done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this either on the server side or on the DNS side.

On the server you can redirect from your base index.html web page to the wiki.

On the DNS side you can probably set this up with your registrar to do the redirect. My registrar has a configuration page where I can set this up. I know it works for ports, but I'm not absolutely sure about paths on your domain.

I think that doing is locally is probably the better solution. That way if you switch registrars you have less work to do and one less thing to break.

Answer (score 0):

With the normal apache server, there's a file at /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf that lets you match server names to document directories.  With virtual hosts enabled you can change the root directory or create subdomains as you like.

Comment: Wiki Server 4 in OS X Server is an app written in ruby on rails i believe. The path http://www.mydomain.com/wiki/projects actually links to a certain place in that app.

Comment: Whether my answer would work or not depends on how the app gets its requests.  The vhosts strategy would be fine for something that's installed as a web app with apache as the front end but not for something that controls its own server port numbers.

Comment: How can i find out which is the case on Wiki Server 4 on OS X Server?